# Unable to set my own directory, and my own site using apache2 in ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I'm using apache2 in a virtual machine with ubuntu server 18.04, everything is going fine, i can see through my PC the welcome page of apache, the server (the virtual machine) and my PC does ping correctly, however, i have a problem.
I need to use this for set up a custom website, i make my `.conf` site in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/gguerrero.conf`

then, inside this `gguerrero.conf` i put the following lanes:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/gguerrero
Alias /gguerrero/var/www/gguerrero
<Directory /var/www/gguerrero/>
Options None
AllowOverride None
order allow,deny
allow from all</Directory>
```

After this, i enable the site using `a2ensite gguerrero` and its enabled correctly, but when i type in my web browser `http://localhost/gguerrero` it just gives me a 'cannot connect' error or something like this, however, if i type `192.168.1.38` (the IP of the ubuntu server running apache2), i get the default site, showing me the apache screen, and it works, but for some reason my server only takes the `/var/www/html` directory, wich the default site (apache default site) is inside, instead of take the directory `var/www/gguerrero` with the `gguerrero` page i made, and it does not work.

Thanks for the help, i appreaciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> i type in my web browser http://localhost/gguerrero it just gives me a 'cannot connect' error or something like this, however, if i type 192.168.1.38 (the IP of the ubuntu server running apache2), i get the default site, showing me the apache screen, and it works

The default configured VM works on a bridge network not localhost. The only way to access it is through the VMs IP from within the host.

> my server only takes the /var/www/html directory, wich the default site (apache default site) is inside, instead of take the directory var/www/gguerrero

Did you restart Apache after making the config changes?

Comment: Yes, i restart apache after every change i made, recently i found i need to edit the `000-default.conf` file and set to the directory i want to use, however, it gives me the typical `forbbiden` error. Also, my virtual machine runs currently under `Bridge mode` and not `localhost`. Thanks for your help.